# What are some useful but less known libraries when working with machine learning?

Tags: machine-learning, python, visualization, library

What are some useful but less-known python libraries when working with machine learning?

For example, I saw these two libraries to help plot the ML plots.

1. [Yellowbrick: Machine Learning Visualization](https://www.scikit-yb.org/en/latest/)
2. [scikit-plot](https://github.com/reiinakano/scikit-plot?utm_campaign=News&utm_medium=Community&utm_source=DataCamp.com)

What are some other useful packages you know that can make my life easy? It can be related to visualization, preprocessing or something else.

**Note:** I already know about popular packages like (numpy, pandas, sklearn, matplotlib, seaborn etc)